# How to redirect to https but keep the host pattern the same

Tags: nginx

I have the below nginx server config that works by redirecting any http request to `https://www.foo.com`

My application has potentially hundres of subdomains also, so I need it to redirect but maintain the sub domain so:

http://asdf.foo.com  -> https://asdf.foo.com
http://abc123.foo.com -> https://asdf.foo.com

How can I do this?

```
server {
   listen       80;
   server_name foo.com www.foo.com;

   location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
      alias /etc/letsencrypt_webroot/.well-known/acme-challenge/;
   }

   location / {
      return 301 https://www.foo.com$request_uri;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a variable [$host](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_host) that you can use for the host portion of the URL.

Change the last stanza to

```
   location / {
     return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
   }
```

Comment: works.  as an added bonus, can I to a root to www for just foo.com?  so foo.com will redirect to www.foo.com ?

Comment: @Blankman If the answer works, why don't you accept it as the correct answer? https://serverfault.com/help/someone-answers . If you have a bonus question, please ask as a separate question.